# CKEditor is not rendered when running capybara tests with js enabled

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rspec, ckeditor

CKEditor is not rendered in browser when running capybara tests for some reason. In development and production modes - everything is OK. CKEditor is precompiled, init part with `CKEDITOR_BASEPATH` is also present. All other js stuff used on the page works properly.

I use this gem in my app - https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor

`CKEDITOR.replace('editor1')`, when I run it from console, hides original textarea also, but editor is not shown (I get only empty space on the place of textarea). And there are no errors in browser's console.

**UPDATE:**

I use `sinon` (https://github.com/travisjeffery/sinon-rails) to set fake time:

```
window.clock = sinon.useFakeTimers(<%= Time.now.to_i * 1000 %>)
```

When I remove this code - CKEditor works properly, but this code is needed to make js and ruby time the same. How can I make CKEditor work properly without removing sinon?

Comment: Probably because ckeditor use settimeout internally???

Comment: in what way? i doubt that should somehow influence on its rendering. i do a few minutes sleep, click everything etc., but it is still not working

Comment: @parag-bhayani, you are right. i was using sinon to set time. i removed it - and ckeditor now is rendered. but how can i make it work not removing sinon?

Comment: i've updated my question with new details

Comment: I have no idea about ROR, so I am kind of stuck here

Comment: actually, it has nothing to do with rails. sinon is a js lib to fake time (so if i need my browser think that today is not today but some other day, i use sinon - to run time-dependent tests). and setting `window.clock` somehow breaks CKEditor's rendering

Comment: then you should use sinon before you start rendering ckeditor, or after ckeditor is rendered

Comment: that might solve your issue

Comment: @parag-bhayani, yeap, that solved the issue :) thanx :)

Comment: added as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is happening because you probably have some timeout somewhere that is halting javascript execution and so editor is not being loaded

you are using sinon for some of your use, which uses delay so then you should use sinon before you start rendering ckeditor, or after ckeditor is rendered

Comment: when I run it like this - everything is OK (function() {
  onLoad(function() {
    window.clock = sinon.useFakeTimers(<%= Time.now.to_i * 1000 %>)
  });
}).call(this);